# How to insert object into std::map while declaration

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, constructor, initialization

**Question:**

I'm trying to insert instance of a class into *std::map* at compile time but getting the below error always.

```
main.cpp:18:12: error: ‘_info’ was not declared in this scope
     _info(1)
        ^
```

line number 18 points to below block of the code

```
15. std::map<std::string, Info > lookup  {
16.      {
17.        "aclk",
18.        _info(1)
19.      }
20.    };
```

**Code:**

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

class Info{
    int _info;
public:
   Info(int info){
     _info = info;
   }   
}; 


 std::map<std::string, Info > lookup  {
  {
    "aclk",
    _info(1)
  }
};

int main()
{
   //dummy
}
```

**Observation:**

When I dynamically create the object I don't see any such errors.

```
const std::map<std::string, Info > lookup  {
  {
    "aclk",
    new Info(1)
  }
};
```

But map being `const` and instance being inserted with `new` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `lookup` is not a member function of `Info`, so it doesn't know about anything named `_info`. If you want to create an object of type `Info`, you should use that name: `{"aclk", Info(1)}`.

Comment: Why not just `{ "aclk", Info(1) }` or simply `{ "aclk", 1 }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to supply an object of the type `Info` instead of its data member `_info`. For example

```
 std::map<std::string, Info > lookup  {
  {
    "aclk",
    1
  }
};
```

This is valid because the class `Info` has a conversion constructor.

Or (if for example the constructor is explicit)

```
 std::map<std::string, Info > lookup  {
  {
    "aclk",
    Info(1)
  }
};
```